# Displaying Webalizer Stats using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, shared-hosting, web-analytics, webalizer

I have a website (www.teahua.com) that is written using ASP.NET (2.0) and C# running on a Debian server using mono.  The hosting provider provides statistic on the website using webalizer.

The statistics is accessed uing www.teahua.com/stats (and it runs the index.html page).

I am relatively new to the ASP.NET arena.  My question is how can I display / include the stats page, and all other links from that page, using ASP.NET.

Thank you for your help

Comment: first view what the error is. for that set `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in your `web.config`

Comment: I should have said. "The statistics normally, for non asp pages, can be accessed using www.teahua.com/stats but because it is a asp.net site it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** - iFrame

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe

**Option 2** - HTTPWebRequest  - Download the webpage, process it, and provide it to your users.

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/285/httpwebrequest/

After downloading the file, you can provide it to your users within a div or literal. Depending on your choice, you may want to strip out key tags, or perhaps the entire header portion of the downloaded file.

Comment: agreed. tht it might offend :)

Comment: Thanks Hamlin.  It keeps giving cannot access "/stats/index.aspx". This only happens for the ASP.NET.  I have no problem accessing the stats from my php site

Comment: Remote in to the server that is serving your ASPX page, open a web browser, and try to navigate directly to the stats page. Does it work? The answer will help the debugging process